# Format numbers in Excel from .9123 to 91.23 without %

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working with Excel 2016 on a Mac, and I am trying to format grades for an assignment. I have calculated various weighted averages, and now I need to format them as "91.23" (for example) rather than ".9123" as they are now. How do I do this?

Comment: Multiply by 100?

Answer (score 2):

You can make it look like you want while keeping the underlying value.

This is a hacky method"

1. Enable `Wrap Text` on the cells.
2. You want a Custom Format.
3. Enter the custom format as follows:

> 1. Enter `0.00`
> 2. While holding down Alt, enter 0010. This will put in a line break
> 3. Put in the %.
> 4. Hit OK

This will put the number in percentage mode but the `%` will be on the second line.  With the cell set as wrap and the cell only tall enough to show one line it will only show the number.

The underlying number will remain the `.xxxx` and not that of `100 * .xxxx`

[image]

Comment: Oooh! Very sneaky!

Comment: This is one of the more clever solutions for Custom Formatting that I've ever seen. I might incorporate this into an upcoming presentation I'm putting together!

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by 100.

```
 =100*A1
```

will work (replace A1 by whatever cell you need). You can even drag this formula down a row/across a column and it will automatically change its target cell.

Comment: That changes the value for calculation purposes rather than just the appearance.